Idiomatic way to get fully qualified table name, with schema
I want to get the names of tables in my database.  As it has multiple schemas, I need the fully qualified name for each in schema.table format.  I can get this with
select schema_name(schema_id) + N'.' + name from sys.tables
or to correctly handle spaces and the like in table names,
select quotename(schema_name(schema_id)) + N'.' + quotename(name) from sys.tables
My question is simply, is there a more idiomatic way to get this?  To get back the fully qualified name as a single string rather than pasting together each time?  Is there some kind of view that provides it?  (I know that the information_schema views are usually best avoided.)
(I don't mind whether the name that comes back is wrapped in [] characters -- for my particular database this quoting is not needed but I accept it may be in general.)
I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2019.

You have the best way that I know of.  The system tables have the data but in seperate columns and why duplicate it in different formats.  The user has all the info and can format it anyway they want.

Thanks for your comment.  I will note that the system tables already have some duplicate information where it's convenient -- for example the name of a table is in both sys.objects and sys.tables.

Your code is fine, but i'd probably use QUOTENAME just in case. But sure, one can do CONCAT instead of +, N'.' instead of '.' too. Some people don't like SCHEMA_NAME because it doesn't respect isolation level of the rest of the query and join the sys.schemas to get the name, but we're talking very picky now

I will add the quoting, but can you explain why concat is better than +?

It's mostly that it looks better, and it will properly handle NULLs in schema if they were to occur, but it's mostly style points

"No", is the answer, as far as I have been able to find out.  You have to look up the schema name and paste a string together.
I have filed this feature request with Microsoft: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/53456c98-d392-ef11-95f6-000d3ae2b698
